# Datediff on one Date Field. Issues with grouping by

Tags: tableau-api, lookup, calculated-field

I have a data set like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYiMr.png

I want to calculate the difference it takes to go from max of processing to min of received.

Here is the desired output table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2juJH.png

Here is the Calculated field I have written so:

```
{ 

INCLUDE [Tracking Item status]: 

MIN([Created Date])- MAX([Created Date])

}
```

Comment: What output is your code producing?  What errors are you experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
{fixed [tracking_item], [tracking_item_status] : Max([created_date])} - {fixed [tracking_item], [tracking_item_status] : Min([created_date])}
```

Comment: Thanks for the calculation Bernardo. Unfortunately it's returning 44 for book and 33 for car... Whereas I want 7 and 15 respectively.

Comment: Can you explain how you get the 7 and 15? I guess I'm confused.